# Bash script that updates Intel e1000e driver

Tags: bash, linux, shell

I am now writing a small bash script that updates an Intel NIC driver to the latest version from the official website. Is there any way to improve\simplify the script? I want to avoid a lot of "if...else" stuff. Helpful tips will be appreciated!

```
#! /bin/bash

DRV_PKG_NAME="e1000e-3.0.4.tar.gz"
DRV_PKG_URL="http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/e1000e-3.0.4.tar.gz"

# Downloading driver and extracting it to current directory
echo "Downloading and extracting driver package..."

if wget -q ${DRV_PKG_URL} && tar zxvf ${DRV_PKG_NAME} >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Done!"
else
    exit 1
fi

# Installing required build dependencies if necessary
echo "Installing build dependencies..."

if apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Done!"
else
    exit 1
fi

# Going into the driver source directory
cd e1000e-3.0.4/src/ 

# Building driver and updating initramfs
echo "Building module and updating initramfs..."

if { make install && update-initramfs -k all -u; } >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Done!"
else
    exit 1
fi  

echo "Purging unnecessary build dependencies..."

if apt-get -y purge build-essential >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Done!"
else
    exit 1
fi

# Restarting iface
echo "Restarting iface!"

{ ifdown eth0  && ifup eth0; } &>/dev/null

# Checking installed driver version
if [[ $(modinfo -F version e1000e) == "3.0.4-NAPI" ]] ; then
    echo "Driver succesfully installed!"
    exit 0
else 
    echo "Something Wrong...Try to re-install!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

### Simplifying the if-else that exit on failure

When the failure case of an `if` exits, you could move the success case out of the `if`, right after it, which will make it a bit shorter. And instead of an `if`, you could further simplify using the `||` operator. For example given this pattern:

> ```
> if cmd; then
>     echo "Done!"
> else
>     exit 1
> fi
> ```

You could simplify as:

```
cmd || exit 1
echo "Done!"
```

You could apply this to all your ifs where you exit in case of failure.

But rather than just fail quietly, it would be better to do as [@dopeghoti](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37726/dopeghoti) suggested and create a `fail` function and print some text in case of failure.

```
fail() {
    echo "$*"
    exit 1
}

cmd || fail 'Ouch, command failed'
echo "Done!"
```

### Excessive comments

You have many obvious comments that add no value at all:

```
# Downloading driver and extracting it to current directory
echo "Downloading and extracting driver package..."

# Going into the driver source directory
cd e1000e-3.0.4/src/
```

In general, it's best when the code is self-explanatory. And in your script it's already the case, so you can remove all comments.

### Error checking

Although you were careful to check errors in general, you forgot one:

```
cd e1000e-3.0.4/src/
```

Sure, if the `tar` earlier was successful, then this directory *must* exist, right? But what if one year later you update your script to get the package from `e1000e-3.1.14.tar.gz` instead and (heaven forbid) forget to update this directory name later in the script? If the `cd` command fails the script will happily continue and run the remaining commands, building whatever source you may have in the current directory instead of the right one. This will be safer:

```
cd e1000e-3.0.4/src/ || fail oopsie
```

### Use more constants

It would be better to move more constants near the top of the file:

```
DRV_BASE_NAME=e1000e-3.0.4
DRV_SRC_DIR=$DRV_BASE_NAME/src
DRV_PKG_NAME=$DRV_BASE_NAME.tar.gz
DRV_PKG_URL=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/$DRV_PKG_NAME
MODULE_NAME=e1000e
MODULE_VERSION=3.0.4-NAPI
```

It will make the script easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid the `if`..`else` constructs you have strewn throughout the script (which is commendable), the best thing to do is to use a `bash` function with an appropriate name (e. g. `fail`) to do the thing you're doing throughout the script for you.  My rule of thumb is that if I'm writing the same code more than thrice, I'm Doing It Wrong and something needs to be abstracted.

Also, `bash` has built-in mechanism for "did that thing I just tried work" tests, namely `||` chains, which execute the command after the `||` if the previous command has a *nonzero* exit code, as well as `&&`, which only executes the next command if the previous command has a *zero* exit code.  For example, if I rewrite one of your `if`..`else` clauses thusly:

```
fail() {
    echo "$*"
    exit 1
}

#  Example:
wget -q ${DRV_PKG_URL} && tar zxf ${DRV_PKG_NAME} || fail "Unable to download from ${DRV_PKG_URL}" && echo "Done!"
```

..if the `wget` succeeds, the call to `fail` is skipped, and we proceed to `echo`.  If `wget` fails, we run call `fail`, which intrinsically exits the script after displaying the specified message.

Comment: `&& echo "Done!"` will not work properly in the following case: `{ make install && update-initramfs -k all -u; } >/dev/null || error_action && echo "Done!"`
`echo` will be executed even if the previous command fails.

Comment: @powerthrash I think that can be fixed with `set -o pipe fail` up at the top of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simplified version of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

DRV_PKG_NAME="e1000e-3.0.4.tar.gz"
DRV_PKG_URL="http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/e1000e-3.0.4.tar.gz"
ERR_LOG="err.log"

# Redirecting all stderr 
exec 2>$ERR_LOG

# Function declaration
error_action () {
    echo "Failed!" 
    exit 1
}

# Downloading driver and extracting it to the current directory
echo "Downloading and extracting driver package..."

wget -q ${DRV_PKG_URL} && tar zxf ${DRV_PKG_NAME} || error_action

# Installing required build dependencies if necessary
echo "Installing build dependencies..."

apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) >/dev/null || error_action

# Going into the driver source directory
cd e1000e-3.0.4/src/ 

# Building driver and updating initramfs
echo "Building module and updating initramfs..."

{ make install && update-initramfs -k all -u; } >/dev/null || error_action 

echo "Purging unnecessary build dependencies..."

apt-get -y purge build-essential >/dev/null || error_action

# Restarting iface
echo "Restarting iface..."

{ ifdown eth0  && ifup eth0; } &>/dev/null || error_action

# Checking installed driver version
if [[ $(modinfo -F version e1000e) == "3.0.4-NAPI" ]]; then
    echo "Driver successfully installed!"
else 
    echo "Something wrong... Try depmod -a or re-install again!"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```